Pipeline build error when code signing .PFX is not found
For the last 5 years, I have been code signing my DLLs and EXEs with a command line task step in DevOps Pipeline.  The .pfx file itself is stored in source control, and retrieved via Get Sources at the start of the build.  Its password is contained in Variables.  After building my code, a command line task calls signtool.exe with the path to the downloaded .pfx, its password and the files to sign etc.  This has worked fine for 5 years!  Last week, it started failing, reporting an error that the file isn't found.  How can i fix this?  The path has not changed!
Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
Code Sign x86 DLLs

SignTool Error: File not found: D:\DevOpsAgent\Agent02\_work_63\s\Code Signing Certificate\abcd-csc-2024.pfx


Has the path to the .pfx file always been the same? Has it always had the spaces?


Please share the completed YAML file of your pipeline. 2. Please check the history of your YAML file to see if there is any change. 3. Check and share the path of the .pfx file in the log of the last successful build.


The path D:\DevOpsAgent\Agent02\_work_63\... looks a little strange, typically it could be D:\DevOpsAgent\Agent02\_work\63\..., can you confirm the path on the local agent directly?

Yes the path has NEVER changed since the build was created years ago

Please confirm the path D:\DevOpsAgent\Agent02\_work_63 in agent machine not your build. Also have you searched the pfx above in the folder, does it exist? If all are fine, check if you upgrade the agent version recently, try to get the version from log before, and reinstall the previous agent for a check.

Who knows, after an update is magically started working again with no changes at all.

After an update it started working on its own automagically.
